# Drawing squares at a specific time in Javascript and moving then

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

For my Final Project, I'm trying to design something like a Guitar Hero, based on JavaScript.

As you know, in Guitar Hero, circles represent the notes that you have to puch at a certain time. I'm trying to do the same, but my notes will be represented by squares.

In my code above, squares move down, but I can't make them move at a certain time. I mean, they all move at the same time, but I want them to move each one when I want.

The most important parts of the code are the vectorSquares array, which has all the squares that I want to draw.

The class Square.

The functions draw() and update().

I hope anyone can help me, I need to finish my final project and I feel really lost right now.

```js
   

   
   c = document.getElementById("canvas");
   ctx = c.getContext("2d");

   c.width = 1000;
   c.height = 600;
    

   
   //Clases utilizadas para dibujar los cuadrados
 //function Start(){  
  
  
   class CanLine {
    
    constructor(x1, y1, x2, y2){
     
     this.x1 = x1;
     this.y1 = y1;
     this.x2 = x2;
     this.y2 = y2;
     this.strokeStyle = "black";
     
    }
    DrawingLines() {  
     ctx.beginPath();
     ctx.lineWidth="2";
     ctx.strokeStyle="black";
     ctx.moveTo(this.x1,this.y1);
     ctx.lineTo(this.x2,this.y2);
     ctx.stroke();
     ctx.closePath();
    }
   }
   
   
   
   class FinalLine {
    constructor(x, y, color) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.color = color;
    this.height = 20;
     this.width = 800;
    }
    draw() {
     ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
     ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
     ctx.fill();
      }
   }
   
   
   class FixedSquare {
    constructor(x, y, color) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.color = color;
    this.size = 80;
     }
    draw() {
     ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
     ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.size, this.size);
     ctx.fill();
      }
   }
   
   
   
   
  
   class Square {
    
    constructor(x, y, color, speed) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.color = color;
    this.size = 60;
    this.speed = speed
     }
    
        
    draw() {
     
     
     ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
     ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.size, this.size);
     ctx.fill();
    }
      
      update() {
     
     this.y += this.speed;
                    if (this.y == 480) {
                    this.y = 0 - this.size;
                 }
    }
    
   }
  
  
      
   //Arrays en los que serán almacenados los objetos para ser dibujados
   
   
   let Lines = [
    
    new CanLine(200, 0, 200, c.height),
    new CanLine(360, 0, 360, c.height),
    new CanLine(500, 0, 500, c.height),
    new CanLine(650, 0, 650, c.height),
    new CanLine(800, 0, 800, c.height)
   ];
   
   
   let Final_Line = [
   
    new FinalLine(100, 500, "purple")
   ];
   
   
   let Fixed_squares = [
   
    new FixedSquare(160, 465, "green"),
    new FixedSquare(321, 465, "gray"),
    new FixedSquare(460, 465, "blue"),
    new FixedSquare(610, 465, "yellow"),
    new FixedSquare(760, 465, "red")
   ];
   
  
   //Array Importante, donde van los cuadrados que se van a mover
   
   let squares = [
   

     new Square(170, 0, "green", 3),
     new Square(170, 0, "green", 3),
     new Square(331, 0, "gray", 3),
     new Square(470, 0, "blue", 3),
     new Square(620, 0, "yellow", 3),
     new Square(770, 0, "red", 3) 
    
   ];
   
   
   
   //Funciónes 
   
   
   
   //Aquí se añadirán todos los objetos que sean necesarios dibujar
 
   function DrawingLines() {  
    
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth="2";
    ctx.strokeStyle="black";
    ctx.moveTo(0,0);
    ctx.lineTo(0,0);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
    Lines.forEach(CanLine => CanLine.DrawingLines());
   }
   

   //var counter = 0;
   var currentTime = 0;
   
   var startTime = Date.now();
   
   function countUp (milisegundos){  //Valor que hay en el vector
     
    var TiempoActual = Date.now() - startTime;
    
    for(i=TiempoActual;i>=milisegundos;){
     
     i = Date.now() - startTime;
     
    }
    
    return true;
   }
   
   
    let tiempos = [3000, 7000 , 10000, 12000, 15000];
    function draw() {
     
     ctx.fillStyle = "white";
     ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
     ctx.fill();
     
        squares.forEach(square => square.draw());
     
     Final_Line.forEach(FinalLine => FinalLine.draw()); 
     Fixed_squares.forEach(FixedSquare => FixedSquare.draw()); 

    }
    
  
   //Función que actualiza cada frame
   function update() {
      
    
    squares.forEach(square => square.update());
    draw();
    DrawingLines();
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
   }
   requestAnimationFrame(update);
```

```css
<style>
  
  
  
  canvas {
   border: 3px solid #000000;
   
   padding-left: 0;
   padding-right: 0;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   display: block;
   border-radius: 5px;
  }
  
  .button {
   background-color: #f4511e;
   border: none;
   color: white;
   padding: 16px 32px;
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 16px;
   margin: 4px 2px;
   opacity: 0.6;
   transition: 0.3s;
   display: inline-block;
   text-decoration: none;
   cursor: pointer;
  }
   
  .button:hover {opacity: 1}
  
    </style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

 <body>

  
  <center>
   
   
   
  </center>
  
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  
   
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Some performance problem when the animation ends, I have to refresh the page everytime.

Comment: Now it is made to draw only once time. When the squares reach the position 465 in the y axis, it finishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I redid your code a bit and optimized it, if you have any questions let me know. The guitar adapts to the size of the canvas, I could have done the same regarding the square sizes but I didn't :) (not hard to do). Let me know if you have any questions.

```js
//TODO: Probably fetch song via XMLHttpRequest and parse as JSON
//TODO: End game when song ends (haven't done that part)
//This is an example
const song = {
  duration: 30000, //in miliseconds, corresponds to 30 seconds
  notes: [{
      string: 0, //index of string 0-4 - this will also define the color: index 0 corresponds to the color "green" in colors array
      at: 10000, //appears at the 10 second mark
    },
    {
      string: 1,
      at: 1000,
    },
    {
      string: -1,
      at: 6000,
    },
    {
      string: 1,
      at: 2000,
    },
    {
      string: 1,
      at: 2500,
    },
    {
      string: 2,
      at: 1500
    },
    {
      string: 2,
      at: 2000
    },
    {
      string: 2,
      at: 3000
    },
    {
      string: 2,
      at: 4000
    },
    {
      string: 3,
      at: 1500
    },
    {
      string: 4,
      at: 2000
    }
  ]
  .sort((note1, note2) => note1.at - note2.at)
  .map((note,index)=>{
      note.visible=false;
      note.difference=null;
      note.accessible=true;
      note.failed=false;
      note.id=index;
      return note;
  })
}

//Max 5 strings, so 5 colors
const colors = ["green", "blue", "yellow", "red", "pink"];


window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  const correct = document.getElementById("correct");
  const errors = document.getElementById("errors");
  const missed = document.getElementById("missed");
  const gs = new GameService(canvas, colors);
  gs.start(song);
  function multipleKeys(event) {
    const key = parseInt(event.key);
    //check to see if number
    if (key !== NaN && key > 0 && key < 6) {
      gs.map[key] = event.type == 'keydown';
      gs.keydownHandler();
    }
  };
  window.addEventListener("keydown", multipleKeys);
  window.addEventListener("keypress", multipleKeys);
  
  //Todo: on game quit, stop SI
  let si = setInterval(()=>{
      correct.innerText = `Correct: ${gs.correct}`;
      errors.innerText = `Errors: ${gs.errors}`;
      missed.innerText = `Missed: ${gs.missed}`;
  }, 100);

});



class GameService {

  constructor(canvas, colors) {
    this.ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    this.then = Date.now();
    this.canvas = canvas;
    this.colors = colors;
    this.size = 20;
    //entities are your square notes
    this.entities = [];
    this.interval = 1000 / 30; //30 = fps
    this.finalLineHeight = this.size;
    this.nbLines = 5;
    this.heightInMiliseconds = 2000; //Notes appear 2 seconds before they reach purple line
    //TODO: Find the sweet spot, for keypress accuracy
    this.latencyFailSafe = 70;
    this.songOffset = 5000; //Song shouldn't start right away, give the player 10 seconds to get ready before notes appear.
    this.requestId = undefined;
  }

  start(song) {
    this.entities = song.notes;
    this.duration = song.duration;


    this.errors = 0;
    this.correct = 0;
    this.missed = 0;
    this.visibleNotes = [];
    this.map = {
      "1": false,
      "2": false,
      "3": false,
      "4": false,
      "5": false
    };
    //record when song starts with 5 seconds delay, so notes don't appear RIGHT away.
    this.start = Date.now() + this.songOffset;
    this.loop();
  }

  //TODO: Not finished
  keydownHandler() {
    for (const prop in this.map) {
      if (this.map.hasOwnProperty(prop) && this.map[prop] !== false) {
        //key was pressed, 
        const note = this.entities.find(note => note.visible && note.string + 1 == prop && note.accessible);

        //if no visibile note found 1 error
        if (note === undefined){ this.errors++; return; }
        
        //check to see if note exists on purple line
        else if (note.difference < (this.heightInMiliseconds * this.finalLineHeight / this.canvas.height)+this.latencyFailSafe){
          this.correct++;
        }
        else{ 
          this.errors++;
        };

        note.accessible = false;
      }
    }

  }

  draw() {
    let now = Date.now();
    let delta = now - this.then;
    //determine if it's the right time to draw
    if (delta > this.interval) {
      this.then = now - (delta % this.interval);
      //Clear rect before drawing
      this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);

      const canvasWidth = this.canvas.width;
      const canvasHeight = this.canvas.height;
      const percentage = 100 / this.nbLines / 100;
      const offset = canvasWidth * .1;

      //DRAWING FIXED ENTITIES FIRST

      //not many fixed entities so no point in instancing them.
      //Also this way, they adapt to the canvas size easily even when the canvas is resized.

      //draw can lines
      this.ctx.save();
      this.ctx.lineWidth = "2";
      this.ctx.strokeStyle = "black";

      for (let i = 0; i < this.nbLines; i++) {
        const X = (canvasWidth * i * percentage) + offset;
        this.ctx.beginPath();
        this.ctx.moveTo(X, 0);
        this.ctx.lineTo(X, canvasHeight);
        this.ctx.stroke();
        this.ctx.closePath();
      }
      this.ctx.restore();
      //draw final line
      //drawn at the bottom of the canvas
      this.ctx.fillStyle = "purple";
      this.ctx.fillRect(0, this.canvas.height - this.finalLineHeight, this.canvas.width, this.finalLineHeight);
      this.ctx.fill();

      //TODO: DRAW FIXED SQUARES HERE
      //Was lazy ;)

      //DRAWING DYNAMIC ENTITIES SECOND

      const milisecondsSinceStart = now - this.start;
      this.entities = this.entities.filter(entity => {
        const difference = entity.at - milisecondsSinceStart;
        //Check to see if note should appear
        if (difference > 0 && difference < this.heightInMiliseconds) {

          entity.difference = difference;
          entity.visible = true;
          const width = entity.string !== -1 ? this.size : canvasWidth;
          const X = (entity.string !== -1) ? (canvasWidth * entity.string * percentage) + offset: 0;
          const H = canvasHeight - canvasHeight * (difference / this.heightInMiliseconds);
          this.ctx.fillStyle =(entity.string !== -1) ? this.colors[entity.string]: "orange";
          this.ctx.fillRect(X - (this.size / 2), H, width, this.size);
          this.ctx.fill();
          return true;
        } else if (difference <= -this.latencyFailSafe) {
          
          //Missed a note
          if(entity.failed === false && entity.accessible === true){
            this.missed++;
            this.errors++;
          }
          return false;
        } else {
          return true;
        }

      });
    }
  }

  loop() {
    if(this.entities.length === 0){ this.stop(); return; }
    this.requestId = requestAnimationFrame(this.loop.bind(this));
    this.draw();
  }
  
  stop(){
    cancelAnimationFrame(this.requestId);
    this.requestId = undefined;
    alert(`Game Completed: correct = ${this.correct}, errors = ${this.errors}, missed = ${this.missed}`);
  }

}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<p id="correct"></p>
<p id="errors"></p>
<p id="missed"></p>
```

Comment: I have no words to thank you for that. This has made me want to continue with this, I was thinking about giving up on my Final Project.

Comment: Hello, I need help again. What I want to simulate is a battery, so appart from the pads notes, I need a bass drum note. I want to draw it like the final line. How could I do this. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Josema_23 First you'll need to add drumEntities property to the game service (similar to entities). Then you'll need to make the guitar take only half of the available canvas widith instead of the full width, then you'll need to draw the two drums (two circles) beside the final line and draw two vertical lines. Then within the draw call (at the very end) you'll need to loop through you drumEntities and draw it beside the final line in the newly available space.

Comment: It's technically the same thing as entities, except the "final line" could be drawn differently. If not you could just simply draw a second final line with two vertical lines instead of 5.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try. But I think I didn't explained it correctly. I want to simulate only a battery, I don't want to simulate any guitar (my fault, I didn't explain it clearly)

Comment: @Josema_23 well if you want them on the same final line, then simply increase nbLines to 7 and add two more colors in the colors array.

Comment: Think I have it. And what if I want to draw something like the final line but moving like the squares? They have different sizes, so I don't know how to assign each size. Sorry if I become a little bit annoying. I'm really new in this language.

Comment: @Josema_23 I don't understand when you say "draw something like the final line but moving like the squares". Are you asking how to individually change the square sizes? Oh, you're asking for a line for when the user needs to hit the base? I'll update the project with an idea I have

Comment: @Josema_23 there I added something quickly, I'll let you optimize it (:. A note with string -1 will now take the whole length of the canvas.